# How can I syntax highlight Ruby range bounds in gtksourceview3.0?

Tags: ruby, gedit

I do most of my coding in gedit, which highlights integers and other syntax. When I use an integer range in Ruby, represented as `0..3` for example, the integers are not properly highlighted and are instead the normal text colour. I checked out `/usr/share/gtksourceview3.0/language-specs/ruby.lang`, but, alas, the solution appears to be much more complicated than I had anticipated. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, right now I may suggest only 'brute force' solution. This task is all about knowing regular expressions.

Here it is.

First of all I decided to define a new regular expression that will match the whole range, instead of redefining `decimal`, but uses the same styles. There are 3 steps.

By the way, [this is a guide](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-tutorial.html) about language spec for gedit.

**Styles**

Let's define styles first.

In section `<styles>` insert before `decimal`:

```
<style id="range" _name="Range" map-to="def:decimal"/>
```

**Matching**

Then in section `<definitions>` insert before `decimal`:

```
<context id="range" style-ref="decimal">
  <match>(?&lt;![\w\.])(([1-9](_?[0-9])*|0)\s*\.\.\.?\s*([1-9](_?[0-9])*|0))(?![\w\.])</match>
</context>
```

This regular expression **matches decimal only ranges** (there is always room for improvement) such as

```
3..7
3...7
3 .. 7
3 ... 7
```

All the used regular expressions are PCRE (Perl compatible). The best to my mind way would be skimming through [Perl Regular Exressions Doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). So you may invent your own and match whatever you want.

**Invoke matching**

To force syntax highlighting use this expression we must put it **before** decimal in the section `<include>`:

```
<context id="ruby" class="no-spell-check">
  <include>
    ...
    <context ref="range"/>
    <context ref="decimal"/>
    ...
  </include>
</context>
```

And restart Gedit!